Oscilloscope is acting really weird
While not connected to a probe it acts fine but as soon as I connect a probe to it it acts up and gives me a weird signal that increases and decreases as my hand gets closer and farther from the probe. I've tested another oscilloscope so I'm sure it is a problem with it and not the probe.
The oscilloscope is a Tektronix 465.
I am trying to get the calibration signal on the oscilloscope but to no avail. The probe is on 1x setting.
Screenshot from a video I recorded of the weird behavior:

There is no answerable question. Also nothing how it is set up. If for example you plugged the scope in to an ungrounded mains outlet, or something else nearby that should be connected to grounded outlet but is connected to ungrounded outlet, you will see 50/60 Hz mains hum.

It is normal for scope probes to pick up electrical noise from the room. Connect the probe tip to the ground clip and repeat. If you still have noise, then you have a problem.

trying to get the calibration signal ... then why don't you connect the probe to the calibrator terminal?

sorry if I didn't give enough information!
what I meant by 'trying to get the calibration signal' is I am trying to get the squarewave signal that should be appearing when I hook it up to the calibration terminal... I hook it up to the calibration terminal, not seen in the picture but I get the same signal as IN THE PICTURE...

You have the "volts per division" set to its most sensitive setting.  The scope probe picks up random noise from the environment and amplifies it so that you can see it.
Turn the "volts per division" to 1 or 2 volts and you will see the wild wiggling disappear.
Most likely the scope you compared it to has the volts per division set higher so you don't see the "wigglies."

I've tried other settings too!
while this is the most sensitive and I get a really wonky signal, it's still there on 1-2 volts. (less noticable, I still see it though.)
the scope I compared it to didn't have wiggles even at the most sensitive setting
it was also an analog oscilloscope

Funny, I get tens of volts by touching the tip of the probe

[Ed: this answer was composed in regards to the original image,

]
This is a real signal.  Take note of the voltage scale, a few mV, and the time scale, a few ms.  It seems to be near mains frequency.  Adjust the trigger settings (AUTO or NORM, CH1 source, AC or DC coupling, variable level) to stabilize.
Move it around and take some measurements: what does the waveform look like, is it sinusoidal, distorted, clipped, peaked?  What is the period?  What are the durations of various aspects of it?  Adjust the waveform position and scale, or use B DLY'D trigger to time-shift and zoom (pull the timebase knob to change B timebase), line it up to graticule (scale) lines and count divisions.  You don't have cursors like new fangled digital scopes, gotta do it all by eye!
If you probe the AC line (with just the tip, don't connect the ground anywhere, and use a properly functioning probe, and grounded instrument), likely you will see a similar signal.  Or holding the probe near various nearby equipment: general wiring and light fixtures are typical sources.  These electric fields couple to your body, hence when you touch (or just get near) the probe, or say an audio amplifier's input pin, you see, or hear, the buzzing signal that is mains AC.
If you're seeing this not just on the probe tip but most anywhere on the probe body or cable, it's likely the cable is frayed.  Those cheap probes are notoriously poor quality and the shield breaks easily.  A new one, or a BNC cable in the interim, will likely serve well. (Don't use a 1x or non-probe to measure mains.)

The scope hook may have a bad connection to probe tip. Or just not pushed fully in.

@Justme Regarding the edit, it's probably both, just a totally broken probe.

WOW,thank you for that detailed answer, I will tinker with it again,I did adjust the trigger settings before and this time but not much changed, the timebase nob for the B timebase didn't do anything when I tried to use it but Ive seen how it should work...
I will try to probe the AC line next time I try to use it again. I have an Idea on how to try to fix this. which is to use a 220-220 transformer to clean up (possibly?) the hum of the appliances. Ive tested out the probes and they're completely fine. if it doesn't work I will talk with the dude I got it from to figure it out as were close.

It would be useful to see what happens when something (like the calibration signal) is actually connected to the scope.
Ah, oscilloscopes of that vintage were things of beauty and a pleasure to use, like driving a sports car. It's not clear that OP should be given the keys to this one.

hey! thanks for answering, sorry if I triggered some people, I can edit it and add a picture of the signal from the calibration terminal too, I still get the same signal though.
I understand what you mean by saying 'driving a sports car' this is my first personal oscilloscope that I've gotten, it is not the first time I'm using an analog oscilloscope though. I have used plenty of analog oscilloscopes from italian to german analog ones in my vocational education, even some digital scopes.
still sorry if you think I am not ready for an oscilloscope yet. I am trying my best though.

The probe tip is not connected to the hook. Remove the hook sleeve and carefully reinstall it, making sure that it connects to the tip of the probe.
Also, as usual in such cases, try with another probe, on another channel, etc.

Thanks for the answer!
I've done that multiple times, being very careful to be sure the sleeve is connected.
I have 2 probes and tried with both... and have the same result. CH2 gives me the same signal.

This is a very high-performance oscilloscope, and there are a large number of ways to get it to display nonsense.
IF being used correctly there are three possibilities: the scope has an internal electronic problem; the calibration signal is not working; and the probe is bad. Trouble-shooting will require eliminating these one by one through systematic testing.
I don't know what OP has access to for testing, so I can't give specific advice. In my lab I would check the probe on another oscilloscope. And the same with the calibration signal. And maybe a signal generator connected with a coaxial cable.

hey! thanks for the answer! I was able to test the probes on another oscilloscope during the day, and the probes are good! the calibration signal doesn't do anything really, I get the same nonsense as I do without hooking up to the calibration terminal. I could try to get a signal generator and test it that way.
